# How to make a UITextField in a table cell become first responder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitextfield

If I have a series of table cells, each with a text field, how would I make a specific text field become the first responder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
    
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        UITextField *textField = [[UitextField alloc] init];
        // ...
        textField.delegate = self;
        textField.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell addSubView:textField];
    }
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**:To make textfield the first responder in tableview simply add this extension to tableView:

```
extension UITableView {
    func becomeFirstResponderTextField() {
        outer: for cell in visibleCells {
            for view in cell.contentView.subviews {
                if let textfield = view as? UITextField {
                    textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
                    break outer
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in viewDidAppear() call becomeFirstResponderTextField():

```
func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableView.becomeFirstResponderTextField()
}
```

Note:
I am considered visibleCells to search through

Comment: Thanks! By running this in viewDidAppear it becomes first responder once screen is visible to user. To do even earlier, you can  override viewDidLayoutSubviews(). But you cannot do in viewdidload as that will not work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text field to become first responder after loading the table view,

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = /* Index path of the cell containg the text field */;
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
// Assuming that you have set the text field's "tag" to 100
UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
// Make it the first responder
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if(indexPath.row==1)
    {
        [cell.txtField becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    
    return cell;
}
```

Above code make `selected(becomeFirstResponder)` textfield in  second UItableView cell.

Comment: In this way you assume that 'cell' has a property 'txtField'. To do this you have to create a custom cell, otherwise add the textField as subview to the cell and then call becameFirstResponder. Correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score -1):

The UITextField inherits from UIResponder, which implements the becomeFirstResponder message.