# tried dismiss keyboard in textfield using custom cell view in iphone?

Tags: uitableview, ios4, delegates, uitextfield, dismiss

i have tried some codes but did't working textfield return keyboardplease anyone help out.

i have tried some link also:
[How to make a UITextField in a table cell become first responder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661271/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-in-a-table-cell-become-first-responder)
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirm that you bind the delegate of textfield that you create with the view controller. And use this delegate method :-

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

This will hide the keyboard when return key is pressed.

Comment: can you explain how did you bind the text field delegate?